# Sphinx LaTeX Table of Contents - avoid toctree nesting of included rst files

Tags: latex, python-sphinx, tableofcontents, toctree

I have a *Sphinx* documentation with the following structure:

```
My chapter title
=====================

Chapter intro part 1
--------------------------
Brief introduction that I would like to have in the start of this chapter...

Chapter intro part 2
--------------------------
Another short section ...


.. toctree::
   :hidden:
   :maxdepth: 2

   folder/subchapter1
   folder/subchapter2
```

When I render the HTML based on this, things work as intended - I have a starting page for this chapter and my sub chapters are available from the side menu.

However, when I build my LaTeX/PDF output, the hierarchy is structured as follows in the Table of Contents and numbering:

```
0.2 My chapter title
- 0.2.1 Chapter intro part 1
- 0.2.2 Chapter intro part 2
  - 0.2.2.1 subchapter1
  - 0.2.2.2 subchapter2
```

What I wanted to have was below:

```
0.2 My chapter title
- 0.2.1 Chapter intro part 1
- 0.2.2 Chapter intro part 2
- 0.2.3 subchapter1 title
- 0.2.3 subchapter2 title
```

Or alternatively:

```
0.2 My chapter title
0.2.1 subchapter1 title
0.2.2 subchapter2 title
```

I realize this is probably an attempt to "hack" the `toctree` concept a bit, but I'm trying to both satisfy my hierarchy requirements for HTML and *LaTeX* with the same code.

I'm using *Sphinx 1.8.5* and default *LaTeX* build settings.

Comment: Your `toctree` is under the heading `Chapter intro part 2` and will inherit its numbering. IMO a more correct structure would be to move the intros into their own chapter index files—`chapter1/index` and  `chapter2/index`—each with their own sub `toctree`, and the subchapter files into the correct `chapterN` folder. Thus your root `index` file is exactly what it should be used for, an index. Alternatively you can create a separate `latexindex.rst` and use that for latex builds, like in [Pyramid's docs](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/tree/master/docs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a structure as below:

```
Hardware
=============================

.. only:: html

  .. include:: hardware/intro.rst


.. toctree::
   :hidden:
   :maxdepth: 2

   hardware/intro
   hardware/installation
   hardware/connector
```

In the `conf.py` I added:

```
if tags.has("output_html"):
    exclude_patterns.append("*/intro.rst")
```

And in my build process I add the tag `output_html` as the standard `html` tag is not accessible in the `conf.py`. With this I got what I wanted.